# Android OpenGL-ES remove alpha channel between 2 textures

Tags: java, android, opengl-es

I have a one class of my square drawing. When I'm drawing this square 2 times, it makes alpha channel between them. Here is the pic: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/25397982/Screenshot_2012-09-13-16-21-22.png So how to fix this mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could disable alpha blending before drawing the square.
You can do this by adding the line glDisable(GL_BLEND) before the gldraw call.

Comment: Thank you, it helps. But how to enable alpha channel? Now for TRULY alpha channel :D

Comment: The alpha blending is done by using the function glBlendFunc. You can read the description [here](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/1.1/docs/man/glBlendFunc.xml)

Comment: Um, ok. I'm trying to call function gl.glBlendFunc(GL10.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL10.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA); And now it draws this: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/25397982/Screenshot_2012-09-13-18-45-35.png

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure what effect you're trying to get, the glBlendFunc defines how every pixel will be blended with its background, so in case the background is black it's alpha will be half. It would help if you could explain what you're trying to achieve.